# How to add multiple key-value pairs to an array of dictionaries (or similar solution)?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am searching for a cleaner way of writing an array of dictionaries in C# (or an alternative), when all of them have the same key-value pairs (only the values differ).

I need to create 3 power plant objects, and all 3 of them need to have different values for the attributes "Dam", "Diversion" and "First", and I am using the different values of the attributes later in the code. I am fairly new in writing code in C#, so when I searched for the best way to solve this problem, I came across dictionaries and decided to use them for it. So far I have created an array of 3 dictionaries in the Program class, and then added the required values in the Main method.

```
static Dictionary<string, int>[] power_plant = new Dictionary<string, int>[]
         {
            new Dictionary<string, int>(),
            new Dictionary<string, int>(),
            new Dictionary<string, int>()
         };

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
   if (i == 0)
   {
      power_plant[i].Add("Dam", 1);
      power_plant[i].Add("Diversion", 0);
      power_plant[i].Add("First", 1);
   }
   else if (i==1)
   {
      power_plant[i].Add("Dam", 1);
      power_plant[i].Add("Diversion", 0);
      power_plant[i].Add("First", 0);
   }
   else
   {
      power_plant[i].Add("Dam", 0);
      power_plant[i].Add("Diversion", 1);
      power_plant[i].Add("First", 0);
   }
}
```

Although, the code works properly, I feel that there has to be a better way to achieve what I need, whether it is a cleaner code using dictionaries or using entirely different types. However, I do not have the required knowledge to think of an alternative.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you could use the collection initializer syntax in conjunction with creating each of your dictionaries there. See here for an overview about the collection initializer syntax with dictionaries: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer

Comment: Can't you simply take out the 3 sets of assignment statements and execute them without a loop? `power_plant[0].Add(...)` and then `power_plant[1].Add(...)` for the next? To have a for-loop counting only to have 1 set of statements for each such value is an anti-pattern, you don't need the loop.

Comment: Also, as a side note, if all dictionaries would have identical keys anyway, why would you not create a class `PowerPlant` with fields/properties for the respective values instead of using dictionaries?

Comment: Here are some alternatives - https://gist.github.com/lassevk/c55d59782b17dca676d17de5af1a5cf0

Comment: Thank you very much @elgonzo. I used a PowerPlant class in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to the C# world! I am not sure what are you trying to achieve, but it seems like you are over complicating your work. Check this:

> I need to create 3 power plant objects, and all 3 of them need to have different values for the attributes "Dam", "Diversion" and "First"

In that case, create a PowerPlant class:

```
public class PowerPlant
{
    public PowerPlant(int dam, int diversion, int first)
    {
        Dam = dam;
        Diversion = diversion;
        First = first;
    }

    public int Dam { get; }
    public int Diversion { get; }
    public int First { get; }
}
```

Then just add it to a list:

```
var PowerPlants = new List<PowerPlant>
{
    new PowerPlant(1, 0, 1),
    new PowerPlant(1, 0, 0),
    new PowerPlant(0, 1, 0)
};
```

Would that help you? Let me know if it does.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly, and looks a way lot cleaner.

Comment: Unless you need dynamic properties only known at runtime, this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

i think it is better to create PowerPlant class with 3 properties Dam, Diversion and First.

```
public class PowerPlant
{
    public int Dam { get; set; }
    public int Diversion { get; set; }
    public int First { get; set; }
}
```

And create a list of the objects

```
static List<PowerPlant> powerPlants = new List<PowerPlant>
{
    new PowerPlant { Dam = 1, Diversion = 0, First = 1},
    new PowerPlant { Dam = 1, Diversion = 0, First = 0},
    new PowerPlant { Dam = 0, Diversion = 1, First = 0}
};
```

Then you can use linq to select the data as you want.

What do you want to do with the data?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I use the data later in if/else statements to help me choice what type of code do I want to execute.